# Sign in with Google Android - how to detect user deauthorised the app

Tags: android, google-one-tap

I have an app where I want user to Sign In with Google and then get the credentials from my own app.

If user does not reinstall the app, I practically have no use for the Google token as I do not intend to call any Google APIs, I just want to not store any PII in my backend.

I have added the One-Tap Sign In with Google as per instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview

Now I have done so that there is a 'Sign In with Google' button and tapping it starts the One Tap Sign In process, and I get back an `idToken`. That token is a JWT that is valid for just 1 hour.

Now as a user I can navigate to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions (or equivalent UI on the device) and remove authorisation for the app.

Interestingly, after I do this if user presses Sign In button again I get back the **exact same** JWT and it is still valid (so it was not invalidated immediately o_O) and the app is no longer listed under `Signing in with Google` list.

The question I have:
How can I detect on my app launch that the user has revoked access to my app using the `https://myaccount.google.com/permissions` UI?

For all other purposes I understand that I can save my own tokens in `EncryptedSharedPreferences` and use those to determine whether I need to show the user a prompt to Sign In.